# Passing `onChange` from parent to a list of children

Tags: reactjs, react-native, next.js

If I have a component set up like the following, how would I go about passing the `onChange` prop to every `DropdownItem`? I know I could add them directly to the `DropdownItem`, but that seems really repetitive.

```
     <Dropdown
       onChange={(s) => {
           setValue(s);
       }}
     >
       <DropdownItem value={"sample"}>
         <>Sample</>
       </DropdownItem>
       <DropdownItem value={"sample2"}>
         <>Sample2</>
       </DropdownItem>
    </Dropdown>
```

I saw some references to mapping through the children with React.CloneElement and updating the props, but that felt like overkill. Maybe it's the best way to do it though.

Comment: Why to pass onChange for all dropdown.item?

Comment: Why is this tagged with **react-native**?

Answer (score 0):

Yes mapping through the children would be the easier and more efficient way.

```
const dropDownList=[
{
  value:'sample',
  child:<>Sample</>
},
{
  value:'sample2',
  child:<>Sample2</>
}
];
<Dropdown
       onChange={(s) => {
           setValue(s);
       }}
     >
       {dropDownList.map((item,key)=>
            <DropdownItem value={item.value} onChange={onChange}>
                {item.child}
           </DropdownItem>)}
```